# Does a flex channel set on remote object gets logged out on its own after some time interval?

Tags: apache-flex, authentication, blazeds, session-timeout

I have implemented the login capability to my application using Flex(Blazeds)channelset login. But there is a strange problem, after about 2 minutes of inactivity if I try to perform any operation I see that my channelset has been been forcefully logged out

Is there some configuration which I need to do in order to prevent this from happening.

I tried adding this in my web.xml, so that the session persists but it didnt help my cause.

`<session-config>
           <session-timeout>10</session-timeout>
</session-config>`

Please provide some inputs if anybody has come acros this kind of issue.

Answer (score 1):

I believe there is a client side and a server side timeout mechanism.  I believe the default Flex one is 10 minutes, but it wouldn't hurt to look through the documentation for it.  The server side one I'm not sure about.

Have you tried to debug it?  Do you see any logs?  What does it say? is It your server logging the client out or the client just quitting?  I'm guessing this is a server side issue.